# Springs MVC and JQuery Ajax for File Upload and want to read the Springs MVC returned String in JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, spring-mvc, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to create an API in Springs MVC for uploading the file. I am using JQuery and AJAX for calling the API. I am able to upload the file, but I am unable to read the String returned by Springs MVC in AJAX Call. Tried many things but didn't find any solution. I would like to request your help. I pasted my AJAX call and Springs MVC code below.

AJAX CALL:

```
         $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",

                 url: "http://localhost:8080/APIUtility/FileUpload",

                 data: data1,        

                 processData: false,
                 contentType: false,
                 cache: false,

                    success: function(data){

                            alert("Success");
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                            alert("error");
                    },
                    complete: function(data){
                            alert("I am from Complete");

                    },
            });
```

Springs MVC API code:

```
    @Controller
    public class MainController {


        @RequestMapping(value = "/FileUpload")
        public String UploadTemplate(@RequestParam(value = "uploadfile") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {



            String FileStatus;



            MultipartFile uploadedFile = file;
            String temp_string;
            file.getOriginalFilename();

            try{

            temp_string = uploadedFile.getOriginalFilename();
            temp_string = temp_string.substring(0, temp_string.lastIndexOf("."));
            System.out.println(temp_string);

            temp_string=temp_string.toLowerCase();

            File serverFile = new File("D://WebContent//"+ temp_string + "-template.xlsx");

            BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
            bout.write(uploadedFile.getBytes());

            bout.flush();
            bout.close();

            FileStatus="Success";
            return "Success" + FileStatus;

            } 

            catch (Exception e) {    

                   return "Fail";
               }





        }
```

Thanking you,
Punith.

Comment: When I used Postman, I see Status as 200 OK received "Success" string.

May I request you to let me know how to read the above Status 200 OK in JQuery AJAX call?

Comment: Please have a look at the data variable in the error function. Maybe it tells us something useful.

Comment: @PunithKumar, could you try `dataType: 'text/plain'` in your ajax options? let me know the status.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna, I did that and I see that statusText is holding "error" even after successful file upload in intended place.

Comment: open browser console and see what errors happen?

Comment: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. This is what I see in Chrome Console. statusText in AJAX call is returning "error" even after file being placed in the correct location.

Comment: Add this header in your server (probably in CORSFilter or interceptor). So that in every response server can send `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin = *'` that's indicate that allow cross domain request.

Answer (score 1):

You have an ajax call here. Try to define the response type of your controller method with `@ResonseBody` annotation.

```
public @ResponseBody String UploadTemplate...
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that. It didn't work for me. It always goes "error" section in AJAX call, in spite of successful transmission of the file. Thank you !!

Comment: Do you have any error logging on console? Or can you inspect the http response and write us some infos about it (http status, etc.).

Comment: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

This is what I see in Chrome Console. statusText in AJAX call is returning "error" even after file being placed in the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your support. I found an answer to the problem listed above.

Problem is with Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS). Earlier, I didn't configure my Springs MVC with CORS.

I just added class WebConfig and added below code, which enabled CORS for my API.

```
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
      @Override
      public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
      }
    }
```